# Using monkeypatch in a Pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest

how can I pass dummy answers to my application so I can test functions?

Code:

```
class Colors:
    def my_colors(self): return colors_split
    # other stuff

class Hobbies:
    def my_hobies(self): return hobbies_split
    # other stuff

colors = input("Colors:")
colors_split = colors.split(",").replace(" ", "")
hobbies = input("Hobbies:")
hobbies_split = hobbies.split(",").replace(" ", "")
```

Test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setup(monkeypatch):
    inputs = iter(["red", "blue", "green"])
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: next(inputs))

def test_my_colors():
    colors = Colors().my_colors()
    assert type(colors) == list
```

My test code doesn't work as I get this:

```
E   OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`.
```

Comment: Don't... put those `inputs` on the module level so they're run as soon as the module is imported?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your program so it doesn't attempt to read input as soon as it's being imported (by Pytest).

A self-contained example you can `py.test this_file.py` (but `Colors`, `Hobbies` and `main` could just as well be a separate module):

```
import pytest


class Colors:
    def my_colors(self):
        return colors


class Hobbies:
    def my_hobies(self):
        return hobbies


def main():
    global colors
    global hobbies
    colors = input("Colors:")
    hobbies = input("Hobbies:")


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setup(monkeypatch):
    inputs = iter(["red", "car", "green"])
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: next(inputs))


def test_things(setup):
    main()  # Populates colors and hobbies
    assert Colors().my_colors() == "red"  # first input
    assert Hobbies().my_hobies() == "car"  # second input
```

Also, insert here the standard admonition about globals being a bad idea, especially for testability.

Comment: Cool thanks. I was going to say, I've been drilled to never use globals. It does the job though...